# TextBox context menu prevents showing AppBar

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

Consider the following page:

```
<Page ... >
<Grid>
    <TextBox AcceptsReturn="True" />
</Grid>

<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <AppBar>
        <Grid>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button Content="Test 1" />
                <Button Content="Test 2" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </AppBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
</Page>
```

So, this is TextBox and bottom Application Bar. Now, when I run this store application on desktop computer, the only way I know to activate the bar is to right-click in the window. However, TextBox built-in context menu is shown, preventing the bar activation. Only when the program just starts, and no actions are done in the TextBox, application bar can be activated by right-click.

Is there any way to show application bar in such situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ContextMenuOpening` event of `TextBox`. Open bottom bar in that event.

```
private void TextBox_ContextMenuOpening_1(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e)
{
    BottomAppBar.IsOpen = true;
    e.Handled = true; //True only if you don't want to show context menu of textbox.
}
```